# Python Multi Processing printing statement multiple times

Tags: python, multiprocessing, progress-bar

I've written this code that downloads a file from the internet and saves it to my computer.

To make it more efficient, I added `MultiProcessing` to my code to be able to download multiple files at the same time and it works, However, It keeps printing the progressbar I added again and again.

What I want is for the progress bars to display once and keep updating, like they would before the Multi Processing functionality is added. I've added my code below to reproduce.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from alive_progress import alive_bar
import requests
import time
import os

def download(url):
    curr_dir = os.getcwd() 

    x = requests.head(url)
    y = requests.head(x.headers['Location'])

    file_size = int(int(y.headers['content-length']) / 1024)
    chunk_size = 1024

    def compute():
        response = requests.get(url, stream=True)

        with open(curr_dir + '\\' + str(time.time()) + '.mp4', 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size):
                f.write(chunk)
                yield 1024

    with alive_bar(file_size, bar='classic2', spinner='classic') as bar:
        for i in compute():
            bar()
        
    print("Downloaded!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    processess = []
    num_processess = 2

    for i in num_processess:
        process = Process(target=download, args=(links[i],))
        processess.append(process)

    for process in processess:
        process.start()

    for process in processess:
        process.join()
```

Comment: Every time you create a new process, you call the download function. Every time you call the download function, you execute with ```alive_bar(file_size, bar='classic2', spinner='classic') as bar:``` which launches a new bar. Call 2 processes get two bars. If you want a single bar, it must be launched in main. You would require extra code to collect feedback from the processes to work out how much has been completed. Probably best done with the processes feeding a queue while the main program constantly polls the queue.

Comment: Alive-progress doesn't support this feature. Use other library such as ```tqdm```. See [this](https://leimao.github.io/blog/Python-tqdm-Multiprocessing/) for example.

Comment: And remember to post a [mre]. You forgot import statements.

Comment: @Galo do Leste, the OP does not want to use a single bar. He wants to use multiple bars for each download.

Comment: @GalodoLeste I want 2 bars for each download function but what happens is that those bars print themselves again whenever they update. I want only a single bar that updates itself

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2**

If you want multiple progress bars, then I would use package `tqdm`.

This is how I would approach it:

1. First find out for each URL how many CHUNK_SIZE chunks there are. CHUNK_SIZE is set at 1024, but consider increasing this for large files. A potential issue is that the `'content-length'` header key is not always present. **In this case, the URL is considered to consist of a single chunk and the progress bar created will be updated only once when the entire file has been downloaded.**.
2. Then each submitted task creates a progress bar whose size is the number of chunks it retrieved in step 1 and designated for a specific position based on its task number. Then the chunks are retrieved and the progress bar is updated. The logic is predicated on the file being retrieved never varying in size when the `content-length` key is present in the fetched header. That is, the size of the file does not change between the `head` and `get` requests being issued so that the progress bar size set from the `head` command will match the actual number of chunks read when the download is done.

In the code below I have commented out specific code pertaining to the writing of downloaded files to disk and have gotten rid of the `compute` generator function, which now seems to be unnecessary. I have also added a delay between successive fetching of chunks so that the progress bar does not progress too fast:

```py
import requests
from tqdm import tqdm

CHUNK_SIZE = 1024

def get_number_of_chunks(url):
    r = requests.head(url, allow_redirects=True)
    headers = r.headers
    if 'content-length' in headers:
        n_chunks, remainder = divmod(int(headers['content-length']),  CHUNK_SIZE)
        if remainder:
            n_chunks += 1
    else:
        n_chunks = 1
    return n_chunks

def download(task_number, url):
    n_chunks = get_number_of_chunks(url)
    response = requests.get(url, stream=True)

    #with open(str(time.time()) + '.mp4', 'wb') as f:
    if True:
        with tqdm(total=n_chunks, position=task_number) as bar:
            for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=CHUNK_SIZE):
                #f.write(chunk)
                if n_chunks != 1:
                    bar.update(1)
                    # For demo purposes:
                    import time
                    time.sleep(.1)
            if n_chunks == 1:
                bar.update(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

    links = [
        'http://localhost/friends/images/nav.png',
        'http://localhost/friends/images/race.jpg',
        ]

    n_writers = len(links)

    pool = ThreadPool(n_writers)
    pool.starmap(download, enumerate(links))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

[image]

**Multiprocessing Version**

If you must use multiprocessing, then thanks to relent95, who showed the way:

```py
import requests
from tqdm import tqdm

CHUNK_SIZE = 1024

def init_pool_processes(lock):
    """
    Note: The lock only needs to be set once for each pool process.
    """
    tqdm.set_lock(lock)

def get_number_of_chunks(url):
    r = requests.head(url, allow_redirects=True)
    headers = r.headers
    if 'content-length' in headers:
        n_chunks, remainder = divmod(int(headers['content-length']),  CHUNK_SIZE)
        if remainder:
            n_chunks += 1
    else:
        n_chunks = 1
    return n_chunks

def download(task_number, url):
    n_chunks = get_number_of_chunks(url)
    response = requests.get(url, stream=True)

    #with open(str(time.time()) + '.mp4', 'wb') as f:
    if True:
        with tqdm(total=n_chunks, position=task_number) as bar:
            for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=CHUNK_SIZE):
                #f.write(chunk)
                if n_chunks != 1:
                    bar.update(1)
                    # For demo purposes:
                    import time
                    time.sleep(.1)
            if n_chunks == 1:
                bar.update(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from multiprocessing import Pool, Lock

    links = [
        'http://localhost/friends/images/nav.png',
        'http://localhost/friends/images/race.jpg',
        ]

    n_writers = len(links)

    pool = Pool(n_writers, initializer=init_pool_processes, initargs=(Lock(),))
    pool.starmap(download, enumerate(links))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Comment: Sorry for that. Ive added the imports now. I'll try this code and get back to you in a while

Comment: I have updated the code to use the progress bar.

Comment: I have updated the code again to use a multithreading pool, which simplifies everything.

Comment: As I commented on the question post, the OP wants to show multiple progress bars for each download, and Alive-progress doesn't support that. See the [multiprocess_examples_2.py](https://leimao.github.io/blog/Python-tqdm-Multiprocessing/) for ```tqdm```.

Comment: @relent95 I sure missed that - will have to revisit my code tomorrow.

Comment: I have updated the code to use multiple `tqdm` progress bars.

Comment: @relent95 The link you cited is for a different situation. There we have 100  tasks being submitted to a pool for which a *single* progress bar is created. Every time a task is completed by the pool the progress bar is advanced one unit. Of course, multiple pools each with its own bar are being created concurrently and to each 100 jobs are submitted. Here we are submitting two tasks to the pool and we want a separate progress bar for each task submitted. The progress bar for each task will show the progress of a single task as it completes its work.

Comment: I recommended to use ```tqdm.set_lock()``` and the position argument of ```tqdm()```. Hmm I will post my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Alive-progress doesn't support showing and updating multiple progress bars. You have to use another library, such as the [tqdm](https://pypi.org/project/tqdm).

The following is an example of using the tqdm for your scenario. The key point is to call the `tqdm.set_lock()` to specify a synchronization mechanism for inter-process interaction and control positions of progress bars via the `position` argument of `tqdm()`.

```
import multiprocessing
import tqdm

def download(url, id, tqdm_lock):
    ...
    tqdm.tqdm.set_lock(tqdm_lock)
    with tqdm.tqdm(total=file_size, position=id) as bar:
        for i in compute():
            bar.update(1)
        bar.clear()
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tqdm_lock = multiprocessing.RLock()
    processess = []
    num_processess = 2
    links = [...]

    for i in num_processess:
        process = Process(target=download, args=(links[i], i, tqdm_lock))
        processess.append(process)

    for process in processess:
        process.start()

    for process in processess:
        process.join()
```

Comment: After I fix the errors in your code, when I run this what I see are two progress bars but only one is advancing and only when it reaches 100% does the other bar immediately go from 0 to 100%. It's *as if* (what's really happening could be different) the other process instance is able to run and make calls to `bar.update(1)` but the updates are not reflected in the display until the other process finishes. You should try running this yourself with, for example, a "file_size" of 10 and simply updating each bar 10 times with sleeping one second between updates.

Comment: @Booboo, on what environment are you running it? This works well on my Linux console.

Comment: I am running on Windows.

Comment: @Booboo, this also works fine on Windows console. Test yourself with [my code](https://gist.github.com/relent95/3045640bf9a8323a5f7aaef78a6b35ff).

Comment: Yes, I see that you figured out that Windows is creating distinct lock instances for each child process because the creation is at global scope and therefore you need to create a single lock (could also be a `multiprocessing.Lock` instance) and pass it to the child processes. But why have a link to runnable code in a comment? You should just update the source in your answer with what is at [my code](https://gist.github.com/relent95/3045640bf9a8323a5f7aaef78a6b35ff) because what you have posted as the answer does not run.

Comment: @booboo, I intentionally posted an abbreviated code(similar to a patch) that can be applied to the original code of the OP. If I post full code for downloading files, it'll heart the readability of my answer.

Comment: The link you mentioned in your comment to me that demonstrates that the code now works under Windows is what I was referring to; I was not suggesting that you post full code - just something  that runs.