# Why I can't use multiprocessing.Queue with ProcessPoolExecutor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, queue, concurrent.futures

When I run the below code:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed
from multiprocessing import Queue

q = Queue()

def my_task(x, queue):
    queue.put("Task Complete")
    return x

with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    tasks = [executor.submit(my_task, i, q) for i in range(10)]
    for task in as_completed(tasks):
        print(task.result())
```

I get this error:

```
concurrent.futures.process._RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 244, in _feed
    obj = _ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 58, in __getstate__
    context.assert_spawning(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/context.py", line 373, in assert_spawning
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/nn.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(task.result())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 451, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 403, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 244, in _feed
    obj = _ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 58, in __getstate__
    context.assert_spawning(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/context.py", line 373, in assert_spawning
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance
```

What is the purpose of multiprocessing.Queue if I cannot using for multiprocessing? How can I make this to work? In my real code, I need every worker to update a queue frequently about the task status so another thread will get data from that queue to feed a progress bar.

Comment: Take a look at multiprocessing.Manager and get your queue from there

Comment: Your question/problem seems to be an example of an [**X Y Problem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) in that you are requesting help with a solution that may not be the best approach to what you are trying to do. Your text seems to suggest that your basic problem is updating a progress bar based on your tasks' progress yet the code you posted does not involve a progress bar and seems to have decided that writing to a `multirprocessing.Queue` will be part of that ultimate solution. But a queue may not be necessary for this. If only you had described in detail your root problem ...

Comment: @Pingu A queue returned by calling `multiprcoessing.Manager().Queue()`  is so much slower than a `multiprocessing.Queue()` and there is an actual way of using the latter with a multiprocessing pool. See my answer.

Comment: @Booboo, I am exploring solutions to solve my actual problem and one good solution I thought was with a queue. Because I want to track the progress of the target function NOT only when it is finished, but WHILE it is processing data. I am exploring some more solutions but, even if the queue is not ideal for that, I made this question deliberately, because I am very interested to learn why it doesn't work (when it should). Maybe in the future, the queue is -indeed- the solution for another problem of mine and I would like to know "Why I can't use multiprocessing.Queue with ProcessPoolExecutor"

Comment: So what I want to say is that I want to know why this solution failed, even if this was not the appropriate one.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the best short explanation I can offer at this time. If you want to know the "whys and wherefores"  of how Python works internally, you need to look at the source, both Python and C-language. The long answer is there.

Comment: Its more than enough, thank you! I am trying your solutions now to see how they work. I will mark your answer as the solution. I just explained myself regarding "you are requesting help with a solution that may not be the best approach to what you are trying to do. "

Comment: Relevant discussion https://stackoverflow.com/q/75233794/16310741

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short Explanation**

Why can't you pass a `multiprocessing.Queue` as a worker function argument? The short answer is that submitted tasks are submitted to a transparent input queue from which the pool processes get the next task to be performed. But these arguments must be serializable with `pickle` and a `multiprocessing.Queue` is not in general serializable. But it is serializable for the special case of passing an argument to a child process as a function argument. Arguments to a `multiprocessing.Process` are stored as an attribute of the instance when it is created. When `start` is called on the instance, its state must be serialized to the new address space before the `run` method is called in that new address space. Why this serialization works for this case but not the general case is unclear to me; I would have to spend a lot of time looking at the source for the interpreter to come up with a definitive answer.

See what happens when I try to put a queue instance to a queue:

```
>>> from multiprocessing import Queue
>>> q1 = Queue()
>>> q2 = Queue()
>>> q1.put(q2)
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 239, in _feed
    obj = _ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 58, in __getstate__
    context.assert_spawning(self)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 359, in assert_spawning
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance

>>> import pickle
>>> b = pickle.dumps(q2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 58, in __getstate__
    context.assert_spawning(self)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 359, in assert_spawning
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance
>>>
```

**How to Pass the Queue via Inheritance**

First of all your code will run more slowly using multiprocessing then if you had just called `my_task` in a loop because multiprocessing introduces additional overhead (starting of processes and moving data across address spaces) which requires that what you gain from running `my_task` in parallel more than offsets the additional overhead. In your case it doesn't because `my_task` is not sufficiently CPU-intensive as to justify multiprocessing.

That said, when you wish to have your pool processes using a `multiprocessing.Queue` instance, it cannot be passed as an argument to a worker function (unlike the case when you are using explicitly `multiprocessing.Process` instances instead of a pool). Instead, you must initialize a global variable in each pool process with the queue instance.

If you are running under a platform that uses *fork* to create new processes, then you can just create `queue` as a global and it will be inherited by each pool process:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed
from multiprocessing import Queue

queue = Queue()

def my_task(x):
    queue.put("Task Complete")
    return x

with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    tasks = [executor.submit(my_task, i) for i in range(10)]
    for task in as_completed(tasks):
        print(task.result())
    # This queue must be read before the pool terminates:
    for _ in range(10):
        print(queue.get())
```

Prints:

```None
1
0
2
3
6
5
4
7
8
9
Task Complete
Task Complete
Task Complete
Task Complete
Task Complete
Task Complete
Task Complete
Task Complete
Task Complete
Task Complete
```

If you need portability with platforms that do not use the *fork* method to create processes, such as Windows (which uses the *spawn* method), then you cannot allocate the queue as a global since each pool process will create its own queue instance. Instead, the main process must create the queue and then initialize each pool process' global `queue` variable by using the *initializer* and *initargs*:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed
from multiprocessing import Queue

def init_pool_processes(q):
    global queue

    queue = q

def my_task(x):
    queue.put("Task Complete")
    return x

# Windows compatibilitY
if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()

    with ProcessPoolExecutor(initializer=init_pool_processes, initargs=(q,)) as executor:
        tasks = [executor.submit(my_task, i) for i in range(10)]
        for task in as_completed(tasks):
            print(task.result())
        # This queue must be read before the pool terminates:
        for _ in range(10):
            print(q.get())
```

If you want to advance a progress bar as each task completes (you haven't precisely stated how the bar is to advance; see my comment to your question), then the following shows that a queue is necessary. If each task submitted consisted of N parts (for a total of 10 * N parts, since there are 10 tasks) and would like to see *a single* progress bar advance as each part is completed, then a queue is probably the most straight forward way of signaling a part completion back to the main process.

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed
from tqdm import tqdm

def my_task(x):
    return x

# Windows compatibilitY
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        with tqdm(total=10) as bar:
            tasks = [executor.submit(my_task, i) for i in range(10)]
            for _ in as_completed(tasks):
                bar.update()
            # To get the results in task submission order:
            results = [task.result() for task in tasks]
    print(results)
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that the "compatibility" pattern is also needed for MacOS

Comment: @Pingu In fact, for any platform that creates new processes using the *spawn* method.

Comment: @Booboo most probably this is the answer I am looking for. I will do some tests and will get back to you soon!

Comment: @Booboo this is a perfect answer. It is exactly what I was searching for. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Booboo regarding the progress bar, as i state in another comment "I want to track the progress of the target function NOT only when it is finished, but WHILE it is processing data". But for this I will make another question because it is completely unrelated to current question.

Comment: @Booboo Actually I just managed to get the required result (live progress bar) with the queue and your way of sharing the queue! If you have any better idea tell me. Thanks again!

Comment: If you need to mark progress of a task, you can create the bar in the main process and then you would have to send "progress reports" back to the main process via a Queue. You could also have the progress bar created by the subtask (since each submitted task will be creating its own bar presumably, it needs to provide a *position* arg to the bar creation so that each bar behaves with one another). {See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75129012/python-multi-processing-printing-statement-multiple-times/75136842#75136842). I have also updated the "short answer" to be more complete.