# How is the multiprocessing.Queue instance serialized when passed as an argument to a multiprocessing.Process?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, queue

A related question came up at [Why I can't use multiprocessing.Queue with ProcessPoolExecutor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75193175/why-i-cant-use-multiprocessing-queue-with-processpoolexecutor). I provided a partial answer along with a workaround but admitted that the question raises another question, namely why a `multiprocessing.Queue` instance *can* be passed as the argument to a `multiprocessing.Process` worker function.

For example, the following code fails under platforms that use either the *spawn* or *fork* method of creating new processes:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, Queue

def worker(q):
    print(q.get())

with Pool(1) as pool:
    q = Queue()
    q.put(7)
    pool.apply(worker, args=(q,))
```

The above raises:

`RuntimeError: Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance`

Yet the following program runs without a problem:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def worker(q):
    print(q.get())

q = Queue()
q.put(7)
p = Process(target=worker, args=(q,))
p.start()
p.join()
```

It appears that arguments to a multiprocessing pool worker function ultimately get put on the pool's input queue, which is implemented as a `multiprocessing.SimpleQueue`, and you cannot put a `multiprocessing.Queue` instance to a `multiprocessing.SimpleQueue` instance, which uses a `ForkingPickler` for serialization.

So how is the `multiprocessing.Queue` serialized when passed as an argument to a `multiprocessing.Process` that allows it to be used in this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wanted to expand on the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75234743/16310741) so I added my own which also details a way to make queues, locks, etc. picklable and able to be sent through a pool.

### Why this happens

Basically, it's not that Queues cannot be serialized, it's just that `multiprocessing` is only equipped to serialize these when it knows sufficient information about the target process it will be sent to (whether that be the current process or some else) which is why it works when you are spawning a process yourself (using `Process` class) but not when you are simply putting it in a queue (like when using a `Pool`).

Look over the source code for `multiprocessing.queues.Queue` (or other connection objects like `Condition`). You'll find that in their `__getstate__` method (the method called when a Queue instance is being pickled), there is a call to function `multiprocessing.context.assert_spawning`. This "assertion" will only pass if the *current thread* is spawning a process. If that is not the case, `multiprocessing` raises the error you see and quits.

Now the reason why multiprocessing does not even bother to pickle the queue in case the assertion fails is that it does not have access to the `Popen` object created when a thread creates a subprocess (for windows, you can find this at `multiprocessing.popen_spawn_win32.Popen`). This object stores data about the target process including its pid and process handle. Multiprocessing requires this information because a Queue contains mutexes, and to successfully pickle and later rebuild these again, multiprocessing must call [`DuplicateHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/handleapi/nf-handleapi-duplicatehandle) through winapi with the information from the `Popen` object. Without this object being present, multiprocessing does not know what to do and raises an error. So this is where our problem lies, but it is something fixable if we can teach multiprocessing a different approach to steal the duplicate handles from inside the target process itself without ever requiring it's information in advance.

### Making Picklable Queues

Pay attention to the class `multiprocessing.synchronize.SemLock`. It's the base class for all multiprocessing locks, so its objects are subsequently present in queues, pipes, etc. The way it's currently pickled is like how I described above, it requires the target process's handle to create a duplicate handle. However, we can instead define a `__reduce__` method for `SemLock` where we will create a duplicate handle using the current process's handle, and then from the target process, duplicate the previously created handle which will now be valid in the target process's context. It's quite a mouthful, but a similar approach is actually used to pickle `PipeConnection` objects as well, but instead of a `__reduce__` method, it uses the [dispatch table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.Pickler.dispatch_table) to do so.

After this is done, we can the subclass `Queue` and remove the call to `assert_spawning` since it will no longer be required. This way, we will now successfully be able to pickle locks, queues, pipes, etc. Here's the code with examples:

```
import os, pickle
from multiprocessing import Pool, Lock, synchronize, get_context
import multiprocessing.queues
import _winapi


def work(q):
    print("Worker: Main says", q.get())
    q.put('haha')


class DupSemLockHandle(object):
    """
    Picklable wrapper for a handle. Attempts to mirror how PipeConnection objects are pickled using appropriate api
    """

    def __init__(self, handle, pid=None):
        if pid is None:
            # We just duplicate the handle in the current process and
            # let the receiving process steal the handle.
            pid = os.getpid()
        proc = _winapi.OpenProcess(_winapi.PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE, False, pid)
        try:
            self._handle = _winapi.DuplicateHandle(
                _winapi.GetCurrentProcess(),
                handle, proc, 0, False, _winapi.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS)
        finally:
            _winapi.CloseHandle(proc)
        self._pid = pid

    def detach(self):
        """
        Get the handle, typically from another process
        """
        # retrieve handle from process which currently owns it
        if self._pid == os.getpid():
            # The handle has already been duplicated for this process.
            return self._handle
        # We must steal the handle from the process whose pid is self._pid.
        proc = _winapi.OpenProcess(_winapi.PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE, False,
                                   self._pid)
        try:
            return _winapi.DuplicateHandle(
                proc, self._handle, _winapi.GetCurrentProcess(),
                0, False, _winapi.DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE | _winapi.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS)
        finally:
            _winapi.CloseHandle(proc)


def reduce_lock_connection(self):
    sl = self._semlock
    dh = DupSemLockHandle(sl.handle)
    return rebuild_lock_connection, (dh, type(self), (sl.kind, sl.maxvalue, sl.name))


def rebuild_lock_connection(dh, t, state):
    handle = dh.detach()  # Duplicated handle valid in current process's context

    # Create a new instance without calling __init__ because we'll supply the state ourselves
    lck = t.__new__(t)
    lck.__setstate__((handle,)+state)
    return lck


# Add our own reduce function to pickle SemLock and it's child classes
synchronize.SemLock.__reduce__ = reduce_lock_connection


class PicklableQueue(multiprocessing.queues.Queue):
    """
    A picklable Queue that skips the call to context.assert_spawning because it's no longer needed
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ctx = get_context()
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs, ctx=ctx)

    def __getstate__(self):

        return (self._ignore_epipe, self._maxsize, self._reader, self._writer,
                self._rlock, self._wlock, self._sem, self._opid)


def is_locked(l):
    """
    Returns whether the given lock is acquired or not.
    """
    locked = l.acquire(block=False)
    if locked is False:
        return True
    else:
        l.release()
        return False


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Example that shows that you can now pickle/unpickle locks and they'll still point towards the same object
    l1 = Lock()
    p = pickle.dumps(l1)
    l2 = pickle.loads(p)
    print('before acquiring, l1 locked:', is_locked(l1), 'l2 locked', is_locked(l2))
    l2.acquire()
    print('after acquiring l1 locked:', is_locked(l1), 'l2 locked', is_locked(l2))

    # Example that shows how you can pass a queue to Pool and it will work
    with Pool() as pool:

        q = PicklableQueue()
        q.put('laugh')
        pool.map(work, (q,))
        print("Main: Worker says", q.get())
```

**Output**

```
before acquiring, l1 locked: False l2 locked False
after acquiring l1 locked: True l2 locked True
Worker: Main says laugh
Main: Worker says haha
```

**Disclaimer**: The above code will only work on Windows. If you are on  UNIX then you may try using [@Booboo's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2823719/booboo) modified code below (reported working but has not been adequately tested, full code link [here](https://ideone.com/maoBio)):

```
import os, pickle
from multiprocessing import Pool, Lock, synchronize, get_context, Process
import multiprocessing.queues
import sys
_is_windows= sys.platform == 'win32'
if _is_windows:
    import _winapi

.
.
.

class DupSemLockHandle(object):
    """
    Picklable wrapper for a handle. Attempts to mirror how PipeConnection objects are pickled using appropriate api
    """

    def __init__(self, handle, pid=None):
        if pid is None:
            # We just duplicate the handle in the current process and
            # let the receiving process steal the handle.
            pid = os.getpid()
        if _is_windows:
            proc = _winapi.OpenProcess(_winapi.PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE, False, pid)
            try:
                self._handle = _winapi.DuplicateHandle(
                    _winapi.GetCurrentProcess(),
                    handle, proc, 0, False, _winapi.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS)
            finally:
                _winapi.CloseHandle(proc)
        else:
            self._handle = handle
        self._pid = pid

    def detach(self):
        """
        Get the handle, typically from another process
        """
        # retrieve handle from process which currently owns it
        if self._pid == os.getpid():
            # The handle has already been duplicated for this process.
            return self._handle

        if not _is_windows:
            return self._handle

        # We must steal the handle from the process whose pid is self._pid.
        proc = _winapi.OpenProcess(_winapi.PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE, False,
                                   self._pid)
        try:
            return _winapi.DuplicateHandle(
                proc, self._handle, _winapi.GetCurrentProcess(),
                0, False, _winapi.DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE | _winapi.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS)
        finally:
            _winapi.CloseHandle(proc)
```

Comment: Very interesting. It clearly won't work for Linux because `_winapi` does not exist.

Comment: It's silly to have done this since I would never use the code, but I believe I got your code to work with Linux after a few modifications (I also added a couple of additional tests). It was necessary to `get` the message that function `work` replies with before you try to join the child process or else you could hang. So to make the logic simpler (you don't want to try to get the reply before the child process has done its `get` or else it will hang), I have provided a separate reply queue. See [demo](https://ideone.com/w0L5RF). Feel free to update your answer with this or not as you wish.

Comment: @Booboo can you confirm that the code works for both spawn and fork on Linux?

Comment: II *seems* to work with *spawn*, but will it always. You should review it. See [new demo](https://ideone.com/maoBio).

Comment: @Booboo I had a look at the code, I am unsure how the method being spawn will affect how the handle should be passed on Linux and neither do I have means to test it right now. I'll include the demo in my answer and add a disclaimer.

Comment: A disclaimer is appropriate because, as I said "It seems to work, but will it always?" and perhaps something might have gotten broken which would only manifest itself later. I personally would never use the code even if we were 100% sure that it works today. But if the code is wrong (a real possibility) perhaps you or somebody else can fix it.

Answer (score 2):

When serializing a `multiprocessing.Qeue` to a `multiprocessing.Process.run` method it is not the queue itself that is being serialized. The queue is implemented by an opened pipe (the type depends on the platform), represented by a file descriptor, and a lock that serializes access to the pipe. It is the file descriptor and lock that are being serialized/de-serialized from which the original queue can then be reconstructed.

Comment: Are you saying that the reason why it works when passing a queue to a `multiprocessing.Process.run` method, which executes in a different address space, is because it is *not* the queue itself that is being serialized but rather its related pipe file descriptor and semaphore, which implement the queue? if so, that is the only answer you need., i.e. one sentence. The first and last paragraphs are unnecessary and detract from the essence of the answer.

Comment: @Booboo yes, that's basically it, i modified the answer to reduce it to only the necessary bits.

Comment: I have modified your answer to make it more precise. If I have made an error then please correct it.

Comment: I am not sure that my question has been *fully* answered. A `multiprocessing.Queue` implements custom-tailored `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` `pickle` methods as you might expect and it's in `__getstate__` that there is a test made by calling `context.assert_spawning`, which is raising  the exception apparently when it is not being serialized for the purpose of serializing a `Process` instance (same is true for class `RLock`, used by a Queue). **This seems arbitrary.**  What would be the danger if this check were not made so that a Queue could be written to a Queue?

Comment: In other words, the serialization code for`Queue` and `RLock` instances makes a check to see under what circumstance it is being serialized and raises an exception in the situation I am interested in. But I don't understand why serialization/deserialization would not work for that case too.

Comment: @Booboo passing a semaphore isn't trivial, on windows it needs to be done with a call to [DuplicateHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/handleapi/nf-handleapi-duplicatehandle), which requires both the parent and child process handle, you can create your own serializable queue, by using a named semaphore, and a named pipe, instead and let the OS handle the linking without the handle, but the current implementation of the queue won't allow that, and to be honest aside from using the queue in a `multiprocessing.Pool` there is no reason why that queue should be serializable.

Comment: Thank you!  I posted my question because there are quite a few posts on this site where people have run into the problem that a queue must be inherited and people, including myself, have provided the standard workaround for a multiprocessing pool but nobody until now has explained why.