# Python Passing Multiprocessing Lock Without Inheritance or Passed as Initial Argument

Tags: python, locking, python-multiprocessing, multiprocess

I am trying to pass a mp.Lock object to multiple child mp.Process instances. However, due to some constraints, I cannot pass the mp.Lock object as an argument at initialization of the mp.Process nor can I subclass mp.Process to contain the lock as a member. Specifically, I need the ability to dynamically provide locks to these child processes -- something Python seems adamant about preventing. I know that both Linux and Windows provide functionality for named locks/semaphores and for sharing of semaphores/locks (typically via initialization of the lock in shared memory). I am only really concerned about getting this working on a Linux system, so Windows compatibility is not required. It may also be relevant to mention that the mp.Processes in question are spawned rather than forked.

Is there any workaround in Python to pass a lock between processes at runtime, perhaps by creating a named semaphore or by placing an mp.Lock in a SharedMemory buffer?

Digging into the Python (3.8) source does not seem to indicate that either of my theoretical solutions will work. However, Spawned mp.Processes do appear to use named semaphores as their underlying synchronization primitive on POSIX systems, so it may be possible to (un-pythonically) access the hidden member mp.Lock._semlock.name and open this particular SemLock from other processes.

Comment: If this is for linux only, one option could be to use a file based locking pattern with [fcntl](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fcntl.html) `flock`. If you do decide to work with windows as well, you could use the msvcrt module. This avoids the need to send data in between the processes, as long as the name of the files you use as your locks can be deterministically assigned from inputs that you do have in the current process.

Comment: For a more detailed answer, you need to provide a minimal example that can reproduce your use-case. As of right now, any answers are going to be pure speculation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75247561/16310741

Comment: @flakes I tried that approach and while it does work, it is much slower than true Mutexes and creates a filesystem dependency that is not ideal. Definitely a workable workaround but looking for a true “pass the mutex” solution. Unfortunately I cannot post any example code (even minimal).

Comment: @CharchitAgarwal this is precisely what I was looking for. Don’t love having to dig into the internals of SemLock but the handle passing solution looks perfect. I may specifically pass that handle through a Unix socket with SCM_RIGHTS to ensure the handle is useable by the receiving process.

Comment: @intenseapple I'm not asking you to post your actual production code. You should be able to contrive a MINIMAL example in code that illustrates the issue.

Comment: @flakes normally I would, and it would be relatively simple to write a contrived example, but given that this work is charged to my workplace it is probably frowned upon to do so. I may update the post in the near future with a contrived example created on my own time though!