# Save dictionary with value of type - "nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet.Synset" encountered TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, multiprocessing, nltk, pickle

I want to save the dictionary in Python which has keys as strings and values of the type:

```
nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet.Synset
```

When I try pickle.dump like this :

```
with open('dict1.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(hypernyms, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

I get the following error :

> TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object

I also get this error if I try to save the dict as a numpy object. I checked other questions on stackoverflow, but they deal with either multiprocessing or saving a deep learning model. I am not sure how that applies here.

Comment: Simply put, the object you are trying to pickle contains a lock, and locks are not picklable. You should reconsider what exact data are you trying to pickle here, since an object containing a lock is fairly complex.

Comment: @CharchitAgarwal - thanks for your comment. Yes, I am trying a work around with strings, but I would prefer this data structure, so trying to see if this is possible in some way.

Comment: If you are adamant, then one way you can achieve this is by replacing the RLock attribute present in the object with a `multiprocessing.RLock` and then follow this answer to make multiprocessing locks picklable https://stackoverflow.com/a/75247561/16310741. Alternatively, if you do not care about the locks and only the other parts of the object, then you can omit it from being pickled by setting a `__getstate__` method on the object class and using a `__setstate__` method to create an entirely new lock when the object is unpickled

Comment: @CharchitAgarwal - Thanks a ton for this info, it would help me a lot! :)