# How to use tqdm and ProcessPoolExecutor

Tags: python, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures, tqdm

I'm creating a program that processes files sometimes very huge files in the order of GB. It takes a lot of time. At first I tried using ThreadPoolExecutor which relatively improved the speed. For example a ~200 Mb file would take about ~3 minutes running synchronously, with ThreadPoolExecutor, about ~130+ seconds. That's too slow for me. I tried ProcessPoolExecutor and it did wonderful. Same work done in about 12-18 seconds. Well makes sense since the task is eating a lot of cpu. Now the problem comes to visualizing the progress of the task. I used tqdm. With threads everything works wonderfully. I can see the beautiful progress. But when I change to use Processpool, the program crashes.

My code looks like as follows:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed
from pathlib import Path
from tqdm import tqdm
import os


class FileProcessor:
    NJOBS = 8 # 4 for multiprocessing
    CHK_SIZE = 1024 * 1024 * 80 # 80 MB


    def __init__(self, fp: str | Path):
        self.filepath = Path(fp)
        self.filesize = os.path.getsize(self.filepath)

    @classmethod
    def _process_chunk(cls, chunk: bytes, pb: tqdm, *somemoreargs):
        # processes each byte, updates progressbar afterwards
        array = bytearray(chunk)
        for i in range(len(array)):
            # do sam' with byte at i
            time.sleep(0.0001) # for large file comment this
            if pb:
                pb.update()
        return bytes(array) # and some more vals

    def perform(self):
        def subchunk(chunk: bytes):
            schk_size = len(chunk) // FileProcessor.NJOBS
            if not schk_size:
                schk_size = len(chunk) # will work on this later
            i = 0
            while (schunk := chunk[i:i + schk_size]):
                yield schunk # and some more info
                i += schk_size

        progressbar = tqdm(range(self.filesize))
        file = self.filepath.open(mode="rb")
        executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=FileProcessor.NJOBS)
        # executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=os.get_cpu_count())
        with progressbar, file, executor:
            while (chunk := file.read(FileProcessor.CHK_SIZE)):
                futures = [executor.submit(FileProcessor._process_chunk, sc, progressbar) for sc in subchunk(chunk)]
                # futures = [executor.submit(FileProcessor._process_chunk, sc, None) for sc in subchunk(chunk)]
                for future in as_completed(futures):
                    # do something with results
                    res = future.result()
                    # progressbar.update(len(res)) # uncomment for multiprocessing
            # do final stuff
```

This works well with multi threads. The progressbar fills smoothly. But when I change to multi processes, the program crashes. I am guessing is due to the fact that "processes not sharing memory space".

So, the question is how can I use tqdm to show the progress smoothly whilst using multi processing. For now I am updating the bar after the process ends: in `for future in as_completed(futures)` but the progress display is rather ugly with big jumps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to use a `ProcessPoolExecutor` instance (you code still shows you using a `ThreadPoolExecutor` instance), then the main process which has nothing else to except wait for submitted tasks to complete can easily be the updater of the progress bar. You now need to arrange for your worker function/method (in your case `_process_chunk` to return an additional value that is the amount to advance the progress bar by:

```py
import os
import time
from concurrent.futures import (ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed)
from pathlib import Path

from tqdm import tqdm


class FileProcessor:
    NJOBS = 4  # 4 for multiprocessing
    CHK_SIZE = 1024 * 1024 * 80  # 80 MB

    def __init__(self, fp: str):
        self.filepath = Path(fp)
        self.filesize = os.path.getsize(self.filepath)

    @staticmethod
    def _process_chunk(chunk: bytes, *somemoreargs):
        array = bytearray(chunk)
        for b in array:
            #time.sleep(0.0001)
            ...

        # Also return the number of bytes processed:
        return bytes(array), len(array)

    def perform(self):
        def subchunk(chunk: bytes):
            schk_size = len(chunk) // FileProcessor.NJOBS
            if not schk_size:
                schk_size = len(chunk)  # will work on this later
            i = 0
            while schunk := chunk[i : i + schk_size]:
                yield schunk  # and some more info
                i += schk_size

        progressbar = tqdm(total=self.filesize)
        file = self.filepath.open(mode="rb")
        executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=FileProcessor.NJOBS)
        with progressbar, file, executor:
            while chunk := file.read(FileProcessor.CHK_SIZE):
                futures = [
                    executor.submit(FileProcessor._process_chunk, sc)
                    for sc in subchunk(chunk)
                ]
                for future in as_completed(futures):
                    _, bytes_processed = future.result()
                    progressbar.update(bytes_processed)
                    future.result()

            # do final stuff


if __name__ == "__main__":
    f = FileProcessor("some_big_file.tar")
    f.perform()
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm doing currently but the progress is not smooth. It just jumps. There is no perception of progress since before a 'jump' you've no idea if there is anything going on because the chunks are relatively big

Comment: Suppose you had 5 10-second tasks to complete and you weren't using multiprocessing. Every 10 seconds the bar would advance 20% however wide the progress bar was. That's certainly not smooth but it is indicative of what is actually going on.  In your problem using an extra process and a `multiprocessing.Queue` instance like the answer posted by Andrej Kesely (why isn't it using multiprocessing?), progress would be smoother because the bar advances  once per byte instead of once per chunk. But the overhead of doing millions of gets and puts to a queue sacrifices performance. (more...)

Comment: If you use smaller-sized chunks the bar would progress more smoothly but the program might be less efficient. Fewer tasks processing larger chunks means greater efficiency but a less smooth progress bar. Why does the `ProcessPoolExecutor.map` method have a *chunksize* argument? So there are fewer, but larger gets and puts to the pool's internal task queue. You are in effect doing your own chunking necessitated by using the `submit` method, which does not support a *chunksize* argument.

Comment: This makes sense. I've tried using queue approach and the results were really really not pleasing. I think I'll stick with this approach. Furthermore I've noticed the progress is worse only with smaller files and it's to be expected because I'm using same chunk sizes for all file sizes. I choose efficiency over cool filling progressbar.

Answer (score 0):

You can spawn one additional process that is responsible for updating the progress bar. To send data to this process you can use `Queue()`.

Here is modified example:

```py
import os
import time
from concurrent.futures import (ProcessPoolExecutor, ThreadPoolExecutor,
                                as_completed)
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from pathlib import Path

from tqdm import tqdm

queue = None


def init_queue(q):
    global queue
    queue = q


class FileProcessor:
    NJOBS = 8  # 4 for multiprocessing
    CHK_SIZE = 1024 * 1024 * 80  # 80 MB

    def __init__(self, fp: str | Path):
        self.filepath = Path(fp)
        self.filesize = os.path.getsize(self.filepath)

    @staticmethod
    def _process_chunk(chunk: bytes, *somemoreargs):
        for i in chunk:
            # do sam' with byte at i
            time.sleep(0.0001)
            queue.put_nowait(1)
        return "xxx"

    @staticmethod
    def _pb_updater(filesize, queue):
        progressbar = tqdm(total=filesize)

        while True:
            how_much_to_update = queue.get()
            progressbar.update(how_much_to_update)
            progressbar.refresh()

    def perform(self):
        def subchunk(chunk: bytes):
            schk_size = len(chunk) // FileProcessor.NJOBS
            if not schk_size:
                schk_size = len(chunk)  # will work on this later
            i = 0
            while schunk := chunk[i : i + schk_size]:
                yield schunk  # and some more info
                i += schk_size

        pb_queue = Queue()

        pb_updater = Process(
            target=FileProcessor._pb_updater,
            args=(self.filesize, pb_queue),
            daemon=True,
        )
        pb_updater.start()

        file = self.filepath.open(mode="rb")
        executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(
            max_workers=FileProcessor.NJOBS,
            initializer=init_queue,
            initargs=(pb_queue,),
        )
        with file, executor:
            while chunk := file.read(FileProcessor.CHK_SIZE):
                futures = [
                    executor.submit(FileProcessor._process_chunk, sc)
                    for sc in subchunk(chunk)
                ]
                for future in as_completed(futures):
                    _ = future.result()

            # do final stuff


if __name__ == "__main__":
    f = FileProcessor("./big_file.tar")
    f.perform()
```

Prints:

```
  0%|                      | 98333/12200314880 [00:04<153:34:42, 22066.56it/s]
```

Comment: I've tried this. Works with ThreadPoolExecutor. With ProcessPoolExecutor it raises error: `oid/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/context.py", line 373, in assert_spawning
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance`

Comment: No I am not returning the queue, and I ran the code as it is, the only changes I made were using `ProcessPoolExecutor` instead of `ThreadPoolExecutor` as it is on your code, and the file name. I made it work by using `Queue` from multiprocessing `Manager` but the performance was detrimentally affected.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75194316/18125313) is how to fix that issue.

Comment: @Michael I've updated the code, now it should work with `ProcessPoolExecutor`

Comment: @Andrej Kesely yeah it's working but I'm afraid the process runs very slowly now.